# What do github assignments mean

Tags: github, project-management, issue-tracking

Recently I opened an issue on github, after some time I also opened a pull request for the same. Today, one of the maintainers of the project `assign`ed the issue to me. This appears at the end of issue page:

```
<me> was assigned by <maintainer>
<maintainer> added this to the High milestone.
```

What does this mean? What am I supposed to do regarding the issue? Google didn't bring up anything useful.

Comment: Is the maintainer misused the `assign` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the GitHub [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users/).

> Assignees clarify who is working on specific issues and pull requests.

Assigning someone to an issue is simply a way to keep track of who is working on what.

Some (but not all) projects may add extra meaning to being an assignee so I suggest checking to see if there is a `CONTRIBUTING` file or section of the `README` that clears this up.